# Can you generally treat $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as a fraction in integrals?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

One of the problems in a sample paper for my exam was to "solve this differential equation":
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = a(120-y)$$ ($a$ is a constant. I renamed the constant and the variables for convenience).

When I looked at the solution they provided, they solved it like so:

$$\left(\frac{1}{120-y}\right) \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} = a$$

$$\implies \int \left( \left(\frac{1}{120-y}\right) \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} \right)dx = \int a\,dx \text{ (integrating both sides)}$$

$$\implies \int \left(\frac{1}{120-y}\right) \, dy = \int a\,dx \text{ (the step I don't understand)}$$

...

the rest is irrelevant to this question (assuming)

So what I'm assuming they did there in the third step is they cancelled the $dx$ via fraction cancellation, essentially treating $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as a fraction. So when can you do that? Can you always cancel the $dx$ when it's multiplied by $\frac{dy}{dx}$? I know you can't always treat $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as a fraction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a fraction calculation. It *looks* like a fraction calculation on paper, but formally, it's a substitution.

$$
\int_a^b f(g(x))g'(x)\textrm{d}x=\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f'(y)\textrm{d}y
$$
is really all that's happening, where $y=g(x)$. If you want to be really accurate, you should assume that you're performing the integration around a point where $y\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=120-y.$ Then $\frac {dz}{dx}=-\frac {dy}{dx},\text { so }\frac {dy}{dx}=-\frac {dz}{dx}$ $$-\frac{dz}{dx}=az$$ $$\frac{dz}{dx}=-az$$ $$z=Ce^{-ax}$$
 $$120-y=Ce^{-ax}$$ $$y=120-Ce^{-ax}$$